# MAMP & PHP “SSL operation failed with code 1”

Tags: php, openssl, ssl-certificate, mamp, self-signed

**EDIT**
I’m on the move at the moment, and only have SO on the Stack Exchange app on my iPhone, so there’s some weird formatting with the quotes in the code below - Apologies! I have real ones in the real code :)

I’ve been trying to figure this out for two days with some other questions on SO, but here goes...

Just trying to use `file_get_contents()` to capture the webpage of another file located on the same server and same domain, and include that. I’m using MAMP with a self signed cert for production (so that I can have the server force SSL etc) so there’s that, and I also have that certificate as “Always Trusted” locally on my Mac as it’s self-signed obviously.

So now I have the issue where I want one page to capture the contents of another.. I initially tried using cURL and it was failing without giving me any exceptions, and no information using `curl_error()` so I switched over to `file_get_contents()` where I get the exception `SSL operation failed with code 1`... `ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed`

I assume this is in issue with OpenSSL not trusting the self-signed (but I thought it used the trusted CA’s of the underlying OS?) and I can’t get it to work using the following stream context:

```
stream_context_create([
   "ssl" => [
      "allow_self_signed" => true
   ]
]);
```

And if I set `verify_peer` and `verify_peer_name` to false, the request is made but HTTPS cookies aren’t sent which breaks the whole thing.

I’ve tried adding the actual text of the cert to the `cacert.pem` file under the OpenSSL directory in MAMP, and set that file in the `openssl.cafile` option in the `php.ini` file as stated in another answer, but alas no luck...

Any ideas? Your help would be much appreciated! Thank you! ☺️

**EDIT 2**
So I tried it again using cURL, and this time got cURL to give me some verbose output to a file, and this is what it gives me (note the line third from the bottom):

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to admin.voyagerisc (::1) port 8890 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem   CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
```

...and this is the file where I have added the raw certificate to the top.. ugh, STUCK!

Comment: `“ ”` are those the actual quotes you used? If so, they need to be replaced with `"`.

Comment: no sorry, I’m on the move at the moment and airport wifi on the laptop ain’t working for some reason, so here I am on the Stack Exchange app on my iPhone typing the code out with my two thumbs ahaha 

Comment: Ok, I'll edit them for you. Edit: done.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Oh you’re a legend thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TLDR; You need to become your own (mini) CA so you have a Root Cert that can be trusted

So after a few painstaking days, I have finally figured this out and I hope below will help those few MAMP / PHP users who will undoubtedly run into this issue!!

Basically, `file_get_contents()` and `cURL` operate above OpenSSL, and (as I have now learnt, I was an SSL noob!) OpenSSL, like every device basically has big list of all the main Certificate Authority's root certificates. So if any certificate has been signed by one of those root certificates in can be trusted in the eyes of OpenSSL.

Now you can go into that file that OpenSSL uses that has all the big root certs, and I thought it would be as easy as placing the raw self-signed certificate of the development site at the top of the list and everything would fall into place. **However**, for some reason OpenSSL wouldn't trust it if it's not a **ROOT CERTIFICATE**.

So long story short, here's the steps:

1. Follow [this guide](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/) to becoming your own CA in literally under 5 minutes. (As a side note, this now means that you can trust **just** the newly created root certificate, and for every development site you want with SSL, self-sign with that root certificate and you won't need to re-trust etc)
2. Once you've trusted the root certificate as per the article, and [pointed MAMP](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Settings/Hosts/SSL/) to the key and certificate for the **specific site**, in your IDE open up the .pem file for the **ROOT CERTIFICATE** that you created, NOT the specific one for your development site
3. For MAMP, the file OpenSSL uses as the core list of trusted Certificate Authorities is located in `/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/` - Open the `cacert.pem` in your IDE as well
4. Now, under the comments and before the first real CA, copy and paste in the raw data of your Root Certificate. You can also add in before that long piece of data (and **BEFORE** the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line) the name you set for your Certificate Authority earlier in Step 1, and format it with the `=`'s as is with the other Certificate Authorities.
5. The usual: Save & restart MAMP

Now, if you're running a local development server with MAMP and have self-signed SSL enabled, you should now be able to make the SSL calls back to the server itself, and have the server trust.... itself? I guess? Weird when you think about it!

As a final note, if you had visited any other similar questions here on SO, you would've seen many answers prompt you to create either a stream context with `get_file_contents()` or set some options with your `cURL` resource that suggested turning `"verify_peer" => false` & `"verify_peer_name" => false` in a stream context, or the equivalent options for `cURL`. I **cannot stress enough** that the approach completely defeats the purpose of SSL and shouldn't even be used for local development, due to the possibility of you forgetting to turn it back on or some other obscure event that causes trust to remain off within production.

The method I described above is more tedious, yes, but it will get you through development until you have a real SSL cert in production signed by a true CA, at which point this won't even be an issue anymore.

Feel free to comment if this explanation is not clear / precise enough, I'm only still getting my head around it! Cheers :)

Comment: Fantastic explanation! It's a bit complex, but worth the effort! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Just tested this further and it looks like the solution may be much easier. MAMP has the ability to generate certificates, so it comes with its own Root Certificate. Turns out that the certificate just isn't listed in the trusted cacert.pem. So I ended up opening `/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/MAMP_PRO_Root_CA.crt` in my IDE, copying the code and adding it to the top of the `/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem` (after the comments). This instantly fixes things without requiring generating a custom root certificate or any new certificates for the individual hosts.

Comment: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem has a 301 redirect html file code?

Comment: Thanks, FrankieDee for the explanation! And thanks RocketFuel for pointing out the shorter way!

Answer (score 6):

As Mike mentioned (see comments), in the current version of MAMP (6.4) there's an invalid certificate file added to /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem. Just open this file and access the link shown in the 301 redirect (https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem), download it and replace the file.

Comment: Thank you this saved me after a whole day of headaches

Comment: Thanks! Easy fix, prevented a lot of stress

Comment: This works for MAMP 5 as well.

Comment: OMG such a simple solution and exactly what I needed. Just fixed Guzzle and the Google Authentication API as used by the Google Analytics and Google Cloud oAuth system, all of which were unable to authenticate because of this bug! Sorry for the keyword spam, just hoping people using those things, or the AIWP Analytics Insights plugin for WordPress will find this if they Google lol!

Comment: The question is WTF is going on over at MAMP HQ that this bug somehow goes back to MAMP 5 and still hasn't been fixed, I don't want to have to remember all this when a new version comes out.

Comment: I just submitted this as a support request/bug report to MAMP: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/838146587372552232/1027986389914099753/Screen_Shot_2022-10-07_at_11.50.38.png

Comment: Just want to say, this no longer had any effect for me. Whatever it did in that moment, it's not doing it anymore. I found a new solution, which is to just go into Keychain Access, find the MAMP_PRO_Root_CA, and mark it as always trust, after that you'll never have to add any of their sub-certs into Keychain Access! The docs explain it! https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Settings/Hosts/SSL/

Answer (score 1):

## Mark `MAMP_PRO_Root_CA` as trusted in Keychain Access

After a ton of hassle and problems related to this, and the situation getting even worse over time as Chrome updated, breaking my automated testing as well, I finally found the solution, as described in [the MAMP docs on SSL](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Settings/Hosts/SSL/).

We simply have to add the root certificate that MAMP uses to sign it's custom SSL certs to Keychain Access and set it to always trust:

- Open **Keychain Access** on your Mac
- Search for `MAMP_PRO_Root_CA`
- Double click it and expand the **Trust** section
- Set **When using this certificate** to `Always Trust`
- Close the little window and enter your system password to save the change

[image: screenshot of this settings popup in Keychain access as described above]

After that, any SSL certs you create through the MAMP interface will work automatically, as far as I can tell! If you've been creating your own self-signed certs through the terminal, you might have to go back and update them, but it's easy and reliable, so I don't see why you wouldn't want to if you're already committed to the hot mess which is the MAMP Pro lifestyle

Here's the UI where you create SSL certs in MAMP Pro:

[image: Screenshot highlighting the "Create a new self-signed certificate" in the MAMP Pro interface]

Honestly, I can't tell if this solution was staring me in the face the whole time, or if it was recently enabled in the new versions of MAMP or Chrome. In the end it doesn't matter. Our long national nightmare is finally over