# MAMP local development - cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, localhost, mamp

I use MAMP as local development environment. I want to implement a Google Auth - but keep getting this SSL Error.

1. As other SO topics suggest, I already added this line of code in my PHP.ini file:

```
curl.cainfo ="C:/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"
```

2. and added the latest CA certificate from here: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html in my PHP SSL folder: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\extras\ssl

**Any ideea how to pass this SSL error on my local enviroment?**

This is the code:

```
$google_client = new \Google_Client();
    $google_client->setClientId($clientID);
    $google_client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
    $google_client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
    $google_client->addScope("email");
  $google_client->addScope("profile");



    if($this->request->getVar('code')){
        $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($this->request->getVar('code'));
        if(!isset($token['error'])){
            $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
            $this->session->set('access_token', $token['access_token']);

            //get Google profile data
            $google_service = new \Google_Service_Oatuth2($google_client);
            $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
            print_r($data);
```

Comment: Please see this related question and simple solution on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68725708/209859

Comment: I have reported this bug to MAMP, hopefully they will fix it in an upcoming version: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/838146587372552232/1027986389914099753/Screen_Shot_2022-10-07_at_11.50.38.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the location of the cacert.pem in your openssl.cnf file to point to the latest version you got from curl.se and you should be right.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the value for "curl.cainfo" didn't help me.
Instead i had to set the value in the "openssl"-section of my *current* php.ini (Find the current "php.ini"-file in shell with command 'which php'.):

Uncomment and set the **openssl.cafile** (path is for MacOS):

```
openssl.cafile="/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cacert.pem"
```

(Downloaded the pem-file as suggested from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html )

Answer (score 0):

The solution [described by @tFranz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69630750/586823) works great! Please note, you can also use your system's cert file instead of MAMP's. This is how I did it:

1. Find the folder that should contain your cert.pem using this line:

```bash
$ openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"
```

2. Open this folder in Finder using:

```
$ open /private/etc/ssl
```

3. Look for a `cert.pem` file. If you have it, you can add it to your `php.ini` file:

```
openssl.cafile="/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem"
```

Answer (score 0):

**BE SURE** you are adding your file location to the correct php version.ini file. After FIVE MONTHS of searching and trying multitudes of solutions, I did a deeper dive into my computer. It turns out I have at least two instances of my php files:
Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.1.13/conf/php.ini
Applications/MAMP/conf/php8.1.13/php.ini

Bottom line: **BE VERY SURE** you are editing the correct file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What I did in MAMP , given production was working correctly and local (MAMP) was just for testing, was to disable the SSL , and it allowed me to move forward. So, if this is your case, just disabling it can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern MacOS (such as 14 - Sonoma, but probably back to 12 or 13), and are still having issues after downloading the new certificates and updating your php.ini files, then make sure you enable MAMP with Full Disk Access otherwise it might have issues finding the certificates due to OS file security.

To enable Full Disk Access for MAMP go to:
System Settings > Privacy & Security > Full Disk Access > MAMP